# Can't get text to align to bottom

Tags: html, css

I recently have had problems forcing this text to align to the bottom of a div. Here is what's happening:

https://jsfiddle.net/d40f37dr/1/

```
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.pinfo {
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
}
```

As you can see, I used positioning to position the div class ".bottom" to bring it to the bottom. However, it forces the text into the picture, which was not what I was looking for. I know I could position it with left, but the images users will be posting will vary with size meaning that the positioning will be off when a picture with different dimensions is used.

So then I tried to do it through vertical-align:

https://jsfiddle.net/d40f37dr/2/

```
.bottom {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.

I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: You want bottom of the image or bottom on right side?

Comment: I want the text on the right side. Right by the image. Like this: http://i.gyazo.com/948e971684c0231cc80c7401c1ae896a.png

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/d40f37dr/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following what you need. Use `position: relative; display: table;` for `pinfo` class and

```
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Will solve your issue.

```css
.xw li {
 position: relative;
 background: #fff;
 border: #b8b8b8;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
 margin: 0 1.618rem 1.618rem 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.list li {
 width: 100%;
}
.list img {
 height: 100px; /* you can use % */
 width: auto;
 float: left;
}
.pinfo {
 height: 100px;
 font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<section class="main list" id="view">
<ul class="xw">
  <li class="np md"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/nkWpdCK.jpg">
    <div class="pinfo"> Ad nostrud cupidatat sed ut excepteur nisi adipisicing lorem officia proident, laboris qui occaecat nisi voluptate cupidatat nisi velit i.
      <div class="bottom">est</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Check [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/d40f37dr/6/)

Comment: Great solution and thank you very much. The best part about this solution is it allows for the image to vary in size and it also allows for multiple lines of text to be above the .bottom class. The problem with other solutions such as height:50, is that it would fix the issue, but if the text resulted in more than 2 lines it would displace the text. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you didn't specify the height of an element, so your `.bottom` block has height of the text, and text aligned just on the bottom of itself, so add something like

```
height: 50px;
```

to your `.bottom` class and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d40f37dr/4/)**

```
.bottom {
    clear:both; 
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <li class="np md"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/nkWpdCK.jpg"/>
    <div class="pinfo"> Ad nostrud cupidatat sed ut excepteur nisi adipisicing lorem officia proident, laboris qui occaecat nisi voluptate cupidatat nisi velit i.         
    </div>
       <div class="bottom">est</div>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for you:

since you were floating the image left and the div had an automated width of 100% it filled the whole

=> therefore the text positioned absolute was aligned correctly to the bottom left.

https://jsfiddle.net/d40f37dr/5/

new Css:

```
.xw li {
    background: #fff;
    position:relative;
    border: #b8b8b8;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    margin: 0 1.618rem 1.618rem 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.list li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.list img {
    height: 100px; /* you can use % */
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
.pinfo {
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    width:87%;
}
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace this css in class bottom:

```
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change .bottom class to .bottom:after

```
.bottom:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```